# Mousechildren Issue

Tags: actionscript-3

Consider the following code.

```
var sParent:Sprite = new Sprite();
var obj:Sprite = new Sprite();
var childA:Sprite = new Sprite();
var childB:Sprite = new Sprite();

sParent.addChild(obj);
obj.addChild(childA);
obj.addChild(childB);

childB.mouseChildren = false;
childB.mouseEnabled  = false;

sParent.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, itemClickHandler);
sParent.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, onHoverIn);
sParent.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT, onHoverOut);
```

Now, I want to detect events on "ChildA" but I do not want to detect children on "ChildB"

```
mouseChildren = false;
```

obviously isn't the solution in this particular case. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it is a limitation or a design feature of ROLL_OVER, check the following program I have changed the ROLL_OVER event to MOUSE_OVER and target and currentTarget are giving the correct sprites :

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;

    public class Main extends Sprite 
    {

        public function Main():void 
        {
            if (stage) init();
            else addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
        }

        private function init(e:Event = null):void 
        {
            removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
            // entry point

            var sParent:Sprite = new Sprite();

            var obj:Sprite = new Sprite();

            var childA:Sprite = new Sprite();

            childA.graphics.beginFill(0xff0000);
            childA.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 100, 50);
            childA.graphics.endFill();

            var childB:Sprite = new Sprite();
            childB.x = 150;
            childB.graphics.beginFill(0x00ff00);
            childB.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 100, 50);
            childB.graphics.endFill();

            sParent.addChild(obj);
            obj.addChild(childA);
            obj.addChild(childB);

            childB.mouseChildren = false;
            childB.mouseEnabled  = false;

            sParent.mouseEnabled = false;
            obj.mouseEnabled = false;

            sParent.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, itemClickHandler);
            sParent.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, onHoverIn);
            sParent.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, onHoverOut);

            addChild(sParent);
        }

        private function onHoverOut(e:MouseEvent):void 
        {
            trace(e.currentTarget.name+ " "+e.target.name);
        }

        private function onHoverIn(e:MouseEvent):void 
        {
            trace(e.currentTarget.name+ " "+e.target.name);
        }

        private function itemClickHandler(e:MouseEvent):void 
        {
            trace(e.currentTarget.name+ " "+e.target.name);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Sadly no go on that. Just tested it.

Comment: Try childB.mouseEnabled = false on its own? That worked for me when mouseChildren was being glitchy.

Comment: childB -> parent -> parent has an event listener on childB -> Parent and has buttonMode true. That might be causing the issue. ChildB and it's parents both have mouseChildren and mouseEnabled as false.

Comment: Update your code with a sample that reproduces the problem, it's hard to guess whats wrong without code.

Comment: Looks like it happens with ROLL_OVER changing it to MOUSE_OVER gives me the correct sprites. Not sure if that will help you though.

Comment: Just tested mouse over. No luck. Event target and currentTarget are 'sParent'

Comment: Did you try the program I pasted? I am running it and getting the 2 different sprites in currentTarget and target.

Comment: I turned all my mousechildren and mouseEnabled to true. And used MOUSE_OVER . Finally getting the right currentTarget. 

Will write an exception there. Still there should have been a way to fix it directly. Thanks a lot for your time. Baris helped a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and solved it with something really unexpectable...

```
var obj:Sprite = new Sprite();
var childA:Sprite = new Sprite();
var childB:Sprite = new Sprite();


obj.addChild(childA);
obj.addChild(childB);

obj.mouseEnabled = false; // this.
childB.mouseEnabled = false;
childB.mouseChildren = false;
```